# Is it possible to set a TTL on a document (i.e. automatically expire) added to the search index?

Tags: amazon-web-services, full-text-search, amazon-cloudsearch

I would like to index data where each document expires x days after its creation date. Is it possible to have a sort of TTL on each document added to the index?

Comment: A simple way might be to put the expiration date as part of the document. Then you can either run a daily process that will delete these documents or your can add to the query today()<expiration_date

Comment: That seems good, even if a little less elegant than the solr or elasticsearch approaches